# Spacemacs auto-mode-alist appears to be disabled

Tags: spacemacs

I've been having this trouble for a little while.  Whenever I open a new file in spacemacs, it always opens in fundamental mode.  I'm on a clean install of spacemacs on windows 10 if that matters.

To see what the content of auto-mode-alist was, I opened the scratch buffer, started an inferior emacs lisp, typed the variable name, and pressed enter.  I saw a lot of output, the first of which was the association of *.el files with emacs-lisp-mode.  So I tried opening a new .el file, but I still got fundamental mode.  I then set auto-mode-alist to contain just the association of *.el files with emacs-lisp-mode.  I opened another new file, but I got the same result.

So here is a question: is there a way to disable the auto mode choosing of emacs? Is there a setting that could possible interfere with it that I might have accidentally somehow set (but I'm on a clean spacemacs, so I don't know how it would happen)?

Note, non-spacemacs emacs works fine.

I should also note that when I open a file with windows line endings, I see lovely ^M characters at the end of all the lines.  Without spacemacs, emacs picks up on the line endings and acts appropriately by hiding them.

Comment: What version of Spacemacs do you use ? master or develop ?

Comment: @syl20bnr I just cloned the repository using the address at the top of my browser. I'm assuming that's master (sorry, I'm not very good with git). I guess I'll try using the develop branch then?

Comment: I never saw this issue you should open an issue on GitHub here: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues

Comment: @syl20bnr done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, this is embarrassing.  I was pressing `SPC f l`, but apparently that is the problem.  `SPC f f` is the correct keypress to find files. `SPC f l` is for opening files in fundamental mode to reduce lag caused by syntax highlighting.